# unable to set ConfirmBox value in Hidden field using javascript

Tags: javascript, hiddenfield

when I click on confirm box button and try to set value in hidden fields it is showing this error:

> Unable to set confirm box value in hidden field using javascript

```
function Confirm() {
  var confirm_value = document.getElementById('<%=hdnConfirm.ClientID%>');
  var answer = confirm("Record saved successfully!want to scan document?");
  if (answer) {
    confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    return true;
  } else {
    confirm_value.value = "No";
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code sample you tried?

Comment: function Confirm() {         
  var confirm_value = document.getElementById('<%=hdnConfirm.ClientID%>');
 var answer = confirm("Record saved successfully!want to scan document?");
            if (answer) {confirm_value.value = "Yes";return true;}
            else {confirm_value.value = "No";return false;}}

Comment: this is my code and i am using this hidden field in asp.net